# Data receiving from excel column and show them in texboxes when value in combo box changed

Tags: c#, .net, oledb

[image][image][image][image]Data receiving from excel column and change them when value in combo box changed.

Here is the code :

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();         
    str = "select * from [Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol] where [Bobin ID]='" + comboBox1.Text.Trim() + "'";
    com = new OleDbCommand(str, con);
    OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader.Read())
    {
        comboBox1.Text = reader["Bobin ID"].ToString();
        textBox1.Text = reader["Slab ID"].ToString();
        textBox2.Text = reader["Döküm Kalitesi"].ToString();
        textBox3.Text = reader["Sipariş Çelik Kalitesi"].ToString();
        textBox4.Text = reader["Standart Kalite Adı"].ToString();
        textBox5.Text = reader["Bobin Planlanan Kalınlık (mm)"].ToString();
    }
    con.Close();
    reader.Close();
}
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated......

Thank u

Comment: Have you debug the code whether it is move inside if statement?

Comment: what is your _Bobin ID_ 's datatype?

Comment: It seems date. But, it is not date. It includes numbers and letters. It is sent by another guy. So, i can not change type of data on excel.

Comment: A friend helped me to read first sheet of excel. It is like this now ;               str = "SELECT * FROM  [" + sheetName + "]";    but my shared code is steel  with  str = "select * from [Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol] where [Bobin ID]= ..., how can i read new code ?

Comment: @Serkan Please edit your question and add the problem you are having - exception, error message, anything

Comment: is it ok Now ? I hope problem is clear now ?

Comment: Your SQL should be Select * From ['Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol$'] and you should use parameterised queries

Answer (score 0):

Excel Sheets names end with a $ and when a sheet's name has spaces in it you must enclose it in single quotes. Thus your SQL should read...

```
 Select * From ['Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol$']
```

You should parameterise your query so properly it will be...

```
Select * From ['Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol$'] Where [Bobin ID] = ?
```

OLEDB parameters are positional rather than named (as in SQL/Server). i.e. you specify them in the order they appear in the query.

Thus your code becomes...

```
OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("Select * From ['Sac Haddehanesi Kalite Kontrol$'] Where [Bobin ID] = ?", conn);
com.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "abc";
OleDbDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
```

You can go through the tables in the workbook by...

```
DataTable TablesList = conn.GetSchema("Tables");

foreach (DataRow TableRow in TablesList.Rows)
{
    if (TableRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().EndsWith("$") | TableRow["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().EndsWith("$'"))
    {
        // Handle the Excel Sheet
    }
}
```

Incidentally you don't show us your connection string in your code. Here's the one I used for the above...

```
conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=E:\Test.xlsx;Extended properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1'";
```

Comment: It works perfectly for me. So I'm afraid that if you are still having issues then there's something else going on that you haven't shown in your sample code. Perhaps you could post more.